# Images generated on server real time to be streamed to android mobile

Tags: android, stream

I am generating a set of images on server. I need to encode and stream these real time to a android mobile, what is the best way possible, best encoder server side to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can just have picutres stored in any format and just download them into device one by one. Only matters are how fast connection do you have, how many pictures do you want to send and how fast whole operation has to be finished.

Images downloaded from server in that way are stored in inputstream, which can be saved into file or used to create Bitmap with BitmapFactory and displayed within application. Be aware of OutOfMemoryError, which occurs while creating big resolution Bitmaps with BitmapFactory, as heap is shared amog all applications and is limited to 16 MB.

As for downloading process you can do that with HttpClient library available in Android.